# How can I get the view to update when I change the model in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding, angular-schema-form

I am asking this question after doing a lot research into similar problems where the view wasn't updating after a change to the model was made in an AngularJS app. The situation is somewhat complicated by the fact that I am using an external library `angular-schema-form`.

I have an object-valued variable attached to the scope called `ediTradingPartner.outbound_uom_map` that `angular-schema-form` uses to generate a form element. An example is as follows:

```
$scope.ediTradingPartner.outbound_uom_map = {
  CHARGE: "EA", 
  DAY: "DA", 
  KIT: "KT", 
  MONTH: "MO",
  SET: "ST"
}
```

When the form is loaded, each of the key-value pairs above generates an input field whose label is set to the key and whose text-value is set to the value. In addition, I add an input field and a button that allows the user to add a new key-value pair to the object. The code that does this is below:

```
$scope.setupUomMapping = function() {
    var addNewUOMButton = $('<button>', { text: "+", 'ng-click': "addNewUOM(new_uom_key)"}),
        newUomKey = $('<input>', { type: "text", 'ng-model': "new_uom_key", placeholder: "New key..."}).css('margin-right', '5px');

    var $el = $('<div>', { id: "addNewUOM" })
        .append(newUomKey)
        .append(addNewUOMButton)
    .insertAfter($('legend:contains("outbound_uom_map")'));

    $compile($el)($scope);
}
```

When the user types something into the input field and presses the button, the method `addNewUOM` is called, with the `new_uom_key` being passed in as an argument. `addNewUOM` is defined as below:

```
$scope.addNewUOM = function(new_uom_key) {
    if (!$scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.hasOwnProperty('outbound_uom_map')) {
        $scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map = {};
    }

    $scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map[new_uom_key] = "";
    console.log($scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map);
}
```

What I want to happen is the addition of the new key `new_uom_key` to the scope variable `$scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map` to result in the view having another input field with the label being the `new_uom_key`. As evidence of the model having changed, if I enter "YEAR" into the input field and press the add button, and then log the `$scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map` variable, I get the following value:

```
{
  CHARGE: "EA",
  DAY: "DA",
  KIT: "KT",
  MONTH: "MO",
  SET: "ST",
  YEAR: ""
}
```

The problem, of course, is that the view does not change in response to the changed model.

Some points:

1. The code was working before and it suddenly stopped working at some point when I hadn't made any changes to either of these functions. (I obviously made other changes elsewhere that broke this functionality).
2. I've tried using `$scope.$apply()` and `$scope.$evalAsync()` but to no avail. The former resulted in an error saying that `$scope.$apply()` was already running, and the second didn't really seem to make any difference (though there was no error).
3. I know that dynamically inserting elements as I'm doing in the `setupUomMapping` function is not the "Angular way" but I was forced to do this because the form within which all of this stuff is contained is generated by a third party library, something over which I have limited control. So I'd appreciate if the answers focused on how *this particular* problem can be solved.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please post an example on Plunker -- if it used to work and then stopped because of some other reasons we can't help you here.

Comment: Trying to get it to work on plunkr...

Answer (score 0):

Is there an html object to which $scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uom_map is bound? If so it should automatically update.

Otherwise, is the $scope.setupUomMapping function responsible for building the view? If so, then what is causing it to fire? If you only build the view on the load of the DOM then there's no reason the view would update. You need to call this function each time the view needs to update.

My suggestion: get rid of the procedural building of a view and create html templates that utilize ng-repeat.

Comment: form#ediTradingPartnerForm(name="ediTradingPartnerForm" ng-submit="onSubmit(ediTradingPartnerForm)" sf-schema="editEdiTradingPartnerSchema" sf-form="editEdiTradingPartnerForm" sf-model="ediTradingPartnerModel")
 is the original object to which the $scope.ediTradingPartnerModel.outbound_uo_map is bound.

The setupUomMapping only builds the input field and button that are used to add additional elements to the form, not the original form structure.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#updating-form). They say that they don't watch the data model deeply for updates. Only if the Form Instance changes. As a result you have to broadcast any other changes. Are you using an outside link (like a cdn) for the library? If it loads the most recent version that might explain what broke the code. They may have changed this recently.